# Taylor series expansion of $\ln \{f(x+\delta x)\}$ around $\delta x = 0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I tried by doing

$$g(y+\delta y)= \ln \{f(x+\delta x)\}$$

Here $\delta y \rightarrow 0$ when $\delta x \rightarrow 0$ and also $g(y)= \ln f(x)$

\begin{aligned}
f(x+\delta x) = & e^{g(y+\delta y)}\\
              = & \large{e^{g(y) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y + \frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y^{2}}(\partial y)^{2} + ......................}}\\
              = & \large{e^{g(y)}\cdot e^{\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y}}\cdot e^{ \frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y^{2}}(\partial y)^{2}} \cdot e^{....+..........}\\
              = & f(x)\cdot e^{\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y}\cdot e^{ \frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y^{2}}(\partial y)^{2}} \cdot e^{...+..........}\\
\ln\{f(x+\delta x)\} = & \normalsize{\ln\{f(x)\} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y + \frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y^{2}}(\delta y)^{2} + .......}.....................(1)
\end{aligned}

I have to find $\Large{\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y}$ and $\Large{\frac{\partial^{2} g}{\partial^{2} y}(\delta y)^{2}}$.....so on

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y &= \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial y}\delta y\\
                              &= \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)(\delta y)
\end{aligned}

How do I evaluate $\large{\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}}(\delta y)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $x$? Or this approach is wrong?

Edit:

We have,

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\delta y &= \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial y}\delta y\\
                              &= \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)(\delta y)\\
                              &= \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\lim_{\delta y\rightarrow 0}\bigg(\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}\delta y\bigg)\\
                              &= \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\delta x
\end{aligned}

Also,

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y^{2}}(\delta y)^{2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\bigg)(\delta y)^{2}\\
                                                   &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg\{\frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg\}(\delta y)^{2}\\
                                                   &= \frac{\partial^{2} \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}(\delta y)^{2} + \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial^{2} x}{\partial x\partial y}\bigg)(\delta y)^{2}\\
                                                   &= \frac{\partial^{2} \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}(\delta y)^{2} + 0, \text{ where } \frac{\partial^{2} x}{\partial x\partial y} = 0\\
                                                   &= \frac{\partial^{2} \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg(\lim_{\delta y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}\bigg)^{2}(\delta y)^{2}\\
                                                   &= \frac{\partial^{2} \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x^{2}}(\delta x)^{2}
\end{aligned}

From(1)
$$\ln\{f(x+\delta x)\} =  \normalsize{\ln\{f(x)\} + \frac{\partial \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial^{2} \ln\{f(x)\}}{\partial x^{2}}(\delta x)^{2}
 + ..............}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Expansion in powers of what and about which point?

Comment: taylor series expansion of $ln\{f(x+\delta x)\}$ around $\delta x = 0$ .

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Applications) may help.

Comment: Can i write $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{\delta x}{\delta y}$ as $\delta y \rightarrow 0$ when $\delta x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Do we have some conditions on $f$?

Comment: $f$ is a smooth continuous function. This problem is derived from a Physics Problem. We have $E$ for the energy level of thermal reservoir and $\Omega(E)$ is the total microstate possible. We move $\epsilon$ energy to the system and then the reservoir can have $\Omega(E-\epsilon)$ microstate. To find the condition so that maximum microstate is achieved, a condition has to be satisfied. To get the result, in one step we need to expand $\Omega(E-\epsilon)$ around $\epsilon = 0$ in terms of taylor series.